# Outdoor or Outdoors

Tags: word-usage

Is one an "outdoor professional" or an "outdoors professional"?

Let us say that one is a medic, guide, photographer, etc.

That is a to say a combination of skills or job titles, rather than one.

Comment: The "s" is necessary. "Outdoors" = the field.

Comment: "*Outdoors professional*" (with `s`) is closest to what you mean, but it wouldn't really apply to a medic or photographer, but more specifically to a guide or [outdoorsman](http://i.word.com/idictionary/outdoorsman). An "*outdoor professional*" (no `s`) would mean a guy with a suit, tie, cufflinks and briefcase who conducts all his white-collar business outside, as opposed to within an office. For someone who works in the "*field*", as @Kris notes, you might use the term "*Field* professional" (which doesn't mean *groundskeeper*).

Comment: For clarity, I did mean a combination of skills, rather than any one of them, but I suspect the same applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *outdoors professional* is a professional whose area of expertise is the outdoors. The construction is analogous to *computer professional* or *wildlife professional*. In general, *[noun] professional* means a professional whose field is [noun].

An *outdoor professional* is a professional who happens to be outside, or who frequently works outside. In this construct, *outdoor* is simply an adjective modifying *professional*. An analogous construct would be *outdoor cat*, a cat that is allowed to roam out of the home, or an *outdoor pool*.